# Feature Selection in R

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science, feature-selection

I'm currently working on a data set. 95k+ rows and about 481 columns. I'm trying to make predictions of income via demographic features within the data set(Linear Regression). I'm limited to 15 features.

I know that a model is only as good as the features you give it, but I'm having trouble selecting the right\best features  while dropping the redundant and "noisy" ones (not all are numeric). What's a good way to approach this task? Using R language.

Comment: As the first-posted "answer" states, you're looking for the field of `Principal Component Analysis`.  Also, there aren't a lot of cases in which you need to convert text or other discrete data into numeric values.

Comment: 95k rows is small. It easily fits into memory.